# Use objectAtIndex:indexPath.row selection to change a scrollview image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitableview, scrollview

I am developing an iOS app that requires the user to search a list in a secondary view, select an entry in the list, and this then closes the view, and adjusts the mainViewController scrollview image to a specific location.

I have stored the selected entry in a variable, but I can't get the view to close, or figure out how to reset the scrollview using my variable. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Where you save the selection, set the mainViewController's content offset.

Then if you displayed your secondary view by [view addSubView:]

Call [secondViewController.view removeFromSuperView];

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the view you want to close. If you are using 
[self.view addSubview:someView] then you can call [someView removeFromSuperview];. If your problem is that your trying to have the view close its self, you can create a function - (void)closeSomeView in your main viewController that closes the view.

As for adjusting the scrollView you just need to create a CGPoint and do something like this

```
CGPoint somePoint = CGPointMake(xPosition, yPosition);
[scrollView setContentOffset:somePoint];
```